# Azure Active Directory - Access Denied in New Portal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Using old azure portal, I am able to navigate to Azure Active Directory. But with the new portal 'Portal.Azure.com', I am seeing 'Access Denied' error message.

This is the below exact message I am seeing in the portal.

"*Access denied.
You do not have access
Looks like you don't have access to this content. To get access, please contact the owner.*"

Comment: Would you be able to share with us the user account you are trying to sign in with?

Comment: It is a gmail account. Thank you Shawn for trying to figure out the issue. I am planning to try the solution from Andy Liu.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use the external account to access Azure AD, such as MSA account(e.g. outlook.com, hotmail.com), and the account from other Azure AD tenant. You may experience the error message as below.

[image]

There are two methods to resolve this issue.

**Method 1**

Log in to new Azure Portal by using the account with Global Administrator permission for Azure AD. Navigate to the **Azure Active Directory** extension, from the **User settings** tab, toggle the setting **Guest users permissions are limited** to **No**.

[image]

**Method 2**

Log in to new Azure Portal by using the account with Global Administrator permission for Azure AD. Navigate to the **Azure Active Directory** extension, from the **Users and Groups** tab, search for the external account, and change the Directory Role to **Global Administrator**.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Andy Liu. I will try this solution.

Comment: @user3276267: Just to check if the information is helpful to you.

Comment: Tried the second method and it is working as expected. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the solution was different.

The **clock** on my machine got de-synchronized (lagging 13 hours behind) and when my browser was encrypting a security token to request a sensitive page at Azure Portal, this token was rejected by server and I received "Access denied" error page.

It seams like "time.windows.com" was providing a wrong world time to my computer (yes, it is insane) - I changed it to "time.nist.gov" via `Control Panel` / `Date and Time` / `Internet Time` / `Change Settings`. It immediately updated my computer with correct time.

Then I signed-out and singed-in to Azure Portal and it started working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

As for me, is was to activate a subscription (adding a card bank).

Then I could access the services on my new Azure account

Answer (score 0):

I signed up with my work email (gmail hosted) account. I am the only user on the account, I am the only account, I am the owner. I cannot access the Azure Active Directory service, not users, nor tenant properties.

Essentially I can't really do anything it feels like. I was able to upgrade to pay as you go and add a card, still can't get to the AD service. I always get no access error.

I don't know where the users and groups tab is. If I try to go to users or groups I get "User has no admin roles" error. How am I the owner and have no access to anything?