# Azure Active Directory disabled in the new portal

Tags: azure-active-directory

Does anybody know if the AAD menu options are disable in the new portal? I was able to manage everything in it until last week, but now the options are disabled. If I switch to the classic portal everything works fine.
I found a similar question ([Azure Active Directory - Access Denied in New Portal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42085672/azure-active-directory-access-denied-in-new-portal)) but in that case it seems the guy was able to click the menu options.
I tried using mail gmail account and domain account, both with Global Admin role.

[edit]

just noticed that the problem happens only in Chorme in regular mode. In Chrome anonymous, Edge and IE works fine.

[edit 2]

problem solved: cleaned all chrome cache

Comment: Are you sure you have selected the right tenant (on the top right)?

Comment: @MartinBrandl yes, right tenant. I noticed that the problem has something to do with my Chrome. Chorme anonymous, Edge and IE are ok :(

Answer (score 0):

No, nothing is disabled, its either the wrong tenant, wrong account, or your account was  stripped of permissions. stuff like that