# Azure Active Directory access denied

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am new to Azure and want to use "login with Microsoft" in one of my web apps.
For this I have created a new account on portal.azure.com.
When going to Azure Active Directory tab in account I am getting this error-
**Access denied
You do not have access
Looks like you don't have access to this content. To get access, please contact the owner.**

I found a similar question where they advice to login with Global Administrator permission for Azure AD.
[Azure Active Directory - Access Denied in New Portal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42085672/azure-active-directory-access-denied-in-new-portal/42106762#42106762?newreg=a788d8c1cb4346b19307c21f21f1424e)

But I don't know what is that **Global Administrator permission for Azure AD** is? I just signed up with my email and that's the one account all I have.

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a "tenant" to do something with AD. [Check the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-create-new-tenant)

In short, login into azure portal, go here https://portal.azure.com/#create/Microsoft.AzureActiveDirectory and create new directory.

Answer (score 0):

Global Administrator / Company Administrator: Users with this role have access to all administrative features in Azure Active Directory, as well as services that federate to Azure Active Directory like Exchange Online, SharePoint Online, and Skype for Business Online. The person who signs up for the Azure Active Directory tenant becomes a global administrator. Only global administrators can assign other administrator roles. There can be more than one global administrator at your company. Global admins can reset the password for any user and all other administrators.

Note: n Microsoft Graph API, Azure AD Graph API, and Azure AD PowerShell, this role is identified as "Company Administrator". It is "Global Administrator" in the Azure portal.

Details about the [global administrator role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-assign-admin-roles-azure-portal)

Assign a [user to administrator roles in Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-users-assign-role-azure-portal)

You need to assign the co-admin as global administrator with using account admin user. Log in to new Azure Portal by using the account with Global Administrator permission for Azure AD. Navigate to the Azure Active Directory extension, from the Users and Groups tab, search for the external account, and change the Directory Role to Global Administrator.